# New to Django. Tried looking at tutorials on how to load css files and not working

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-staticfiles

The website I see when I run the server has not CSS in it, but just the HTML. So far I read that you keep CSS files in a static folder under the project directory. I have an Html template that is in the templates folder and it works perfectly when I load it from the views.home . In the HTML file, I have {% load staticfiles %} at the top of the document, and yes I have checked my installed apps for 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in the settings. Also, in the HTML document, in the href attribute I've added {% static 'style/style.css' %} which is the name of the folder under the static folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>

<head>
  <title>night_sky_2</title>
  <meta name="description" content="website description" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" 
/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style/style.css' 
  %}" />
</head>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. All I had to do was add this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
'DjangoProjects\Sample\website\static'
)
```

In the settings and also moved:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

To the very top of the HTML document, instead of under. I put it under at first because it wasn't giving a red line which to me seems like there isn't an error.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have done right in your html template do load the static file. Have you done this configuration in your settings.py ?

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

I've read in this doc that the { % loadstatic %} has been done as {% load static %} just.

See: [django docs about sttic files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: I've looked in my django projects and the only different thing in my code from yours is this slash in the path beginning before the "/style" <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/style/style.css' 
  %}" />

Answer (score 0):

Its easier than you think, but almost everyone gets it wrong the first time. There was a lightning talk about it at the DjangoCon Europe a couple of days ago: https://youtu.be/eEZYDDaDeCs?t=29m50s